# Unable to create new host using Foreman API - missing finishing template

Tags: foreman

I'm hoping this belongs on server fault...

I'm trying to create a host using the foreman API (using hammer, but POSTing the host payload gives me the same result). Each time, it complains that I'm lacking a finishing template.

The error message from the API is this: No finish templates were found for this host, make sure you define at least one in your CentOS 6.7 settings

How do I specify a finishing template when creating a host via Foreman API?

Nothing in the documentation tells me how to provide a finishing template selection when creating the host. Doing this in the Foreman UI with the same settings works just fine. When I click on "Resolve" in the provisioning templates section, I can see my finishing template as well.

Some details: this is Foreman 1.10.1 against a VMWare Cluster

Here's my host payload

```
  "host" => {
                          "name" => "ez-apitesthost",
                   "location_id" => 1,
               "organization_id" => 5,
                "environment_id" => 9,
               "architecture_id" => 1,
            "operatingsystem_id" => 2,
           "compute_resource_id" => 2,
                     "root_pass" => "password",
                  "hostgroup_id" => 73,
                      "image_id" => 19,
                         "build" => true,
                       "enabled" => true,
              "provision_method" => "image",
                       "managed" => true,
            "compute_profile_id" => 11,
            "compute_attributes" => {
                        "cpus" => "1",
              "corespersocket" => "2",
                   "memory_mb" => "4096",
                     "cluster" => "MYCLUSTER01",
                        "path" => "/Datacenters/MYDC/vm",
                    "guest_id" => "centos64Guest",
        "scsi_controller-type" => "ParaVirtualSCSIController"
          "volumes_attributes" => {
            "0" => {
                "datastore" => "dc_sata_01"
            }
        }
    },
                      "owner_id" => "75",
                     "overwrite" => true,
    "host_parameters_attributes" => {},
         "interfaces_attributes" => {
        "0" => {
                          "type" => "interface",
                          "name" => "ez-apitesthost",
                     "domain_id" => "1",
                     "subnet_id" => "2",
                       "managed" => "false",
                       "primary" => "true",
                     "provision" => "true",
            "compute_attributes" => {
                   "type" => "VirtualVmxnet3",
                "network" => "internal vlan"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here's the response

```
{
"error" => {
               "id" => nil,
           "errors" => {
                       "base" => [
            [0] "No finish templates were found for this host, make sure you define at least one in your CentOS 6.7 settings"
        ],
                   "conflict" => [],
        "interfaces.conflict" => []
    },
    "full_messages" => [
        [0] "No finish templates were found for this host, make sure you define at least one in your CentOS 6.7 settings"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to come back to this, I ended up resolving the issue as a permissions problem. That said, the payload I posted will NOT create a host correctly because it's actually somewhat erroneous. However, the error I posted goes away if you call the API (or use hammer) using an administrator user.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that the OS you're using has no finish template associated to it. That's not something you have to do when creating a host, but when creating the OS.

Go to Hosts > Operating Systems > CentOS 6.7 and choose a finish template from the list in there. If you don't have any, I'd recommend choosing Kickstart finish. What it does is just installing Puppet and telling Foreman 'hey! I finished installing :)'

Here's what you're looking for:

[image: OS finish template selection]

If you don't see any finish templates, go to Host > Provisioning Templates, look for 'Kickstart default finish' and associate it with CentOS 6.7. After that you should be able to set it. This is what you should see:

[image: provisioning templates associate with OS]

---

Once your OS has a finish template associated with it, it should resolve just fine. If it cannot find a finish template even in this case, ensure you're providing the right OS options.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So to be clear, this action works fine in the UI. It's when I tried to send in the same request via the API that it fails with this error. I realize I must be missing _something_, but I don't see a way to provide a finish template and I believe the OS/Image combination I've chosen already has the right finish template associated. This is quite a head scratcher.

Comment: @SeafoodBuffet you can always submit a host like the one you want to create through the UI, then look at /var/log/foreman/production.log and see what's the hash submitted. The log should contain the right params and you can compare that to those of your API request. Let us know what was the difference though!